# Python convert IP range to CIDR notation while loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with IP information.  The goal is to create a new column "CIDR" with the conversion of the "StartAddress" and "EndAddress".  There is a python library for the conversion, "netaddr".  I am having issues with the while loop where it keeps hanging for a long period of time.  I have run into this issue before and it is usually a simple fix but as much as I change the while loop I can't figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The data with the empty "CIDR" column:

```
    Name                    StartAddress    EndAddress  City    CountryCode ASN CIDR
0   LACNIC-ERX-128-201-0-0  128.201.0.0 128.201.255.255 Montevideo  \N  AS8048  
1   LN-ERX-129-90-0-0       129.90.0.0  129.90.255.255  Montevideo  \N  AS8048  
2   LACNIC-ERX-131-0-0-0    131.0.0.0   131.0.255.255   Montevideo  \N  AS8048  
3   LACNIC-ERX-131-100-0-0  131.100.0.0 131.100.255.255 Montevideo  \N  AS8048  
4   LACNIC-ERX-131-108-0-0  131.108.0.0 131.108.255.255 Montevideo  \N  AS8048  
5   LACNIC-ERX-131-161-0-0  131.161.0.0 131.161.255.255 Montevideo  \N  AS8048  
6   LACNIC-ERX-131-178-0-0  131.178.0.0 131.178.255.255 Montevideo  \N  AS8048  
7   LACNIC-ERX-131-196-0-0  131.196.0.0 131.196.255.255 Montevideo  \N  AS8048  
8   LACNIC-ERX-131-221-0-0  131.221.0.0 131.221.255.255 Montevideo  \N  AS8048  
9   LACNIC-ERX-131-255-0-0  131.255.0.0 131.255.255.255 Montevideo  \N  AS8048
```

The code:

```
#Import libraries
import pandas as pd
from netaddr import *
import netaddr
import pprint

#Read in data
AS = pd.read_csv('BulkWhois/ARIN/AS8048.csv', sep='|', names=("Name", "StartAddress", "EndAddress", "City", "CountryCode", "ASN"))

#Drop rows where IPV6
AS = AS[AS.EndAddress.str.contains(":") == False]

#Number of rows
lenth = len(AS)

#Create column "CIDR"
AS["CIDR"] = ""

#While loop
index = 0
while (index < lenth):
  AS["CIDR"].iloc[index] = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(AS.StartAddress.iloc[index], AS.EndAddress.iloc[index])    
  index=index + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your function and while loop and it was working but a little bit slow. Probably your problem is that it's taking too long to run.

I would suggest you write a function and use `df.apply()`:

```
def helper(row):
    return netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(row.StartAddress, row.EndAddress)    

df["CIDR"] = df.apply(helper, axis=1)
```

This gave me result instantly where as the while loop took much longer on your sample data.

Comment: That is extremely fast and produced exactly what I was looking for. Thank you  @Yilun Zhang

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a for loop:

```
for i in AS.index:
    AS.loc[i, "CIDR"] = netaddr.iprange_to_cidrs(AS.loc[i, 'StartAddress'], AS.loc[i, 'EndAddress'])
```

But the solution suggested by Yilun Zhang is more elegant.